# CKEditor: Controlling Entermode with a toolbar button

Tags: ckeditor

By default, CKEditor's enter key behavior is adding a `<p>` tag and starting a new paragraph. But that behavior can be modified in the configuration with a `.EnterMode` parameter.

I'm wondering if there is a way to change Enter key behavior in the runtime, by putting a button into its tool bar, to switch between `<p>` and `<br>` (single line vs double line), just like as in Word.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Save the following to `editor_dir/plugins/entermode/plugin.js`:

```
'use strict';

(function() {
    CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'entermode', {
        icons: 'entermode',
        init: function( editor ) {
            var enterP = new enterModeCommand( editor, CKEDITOR.ENTER_P );
            var enterBR = new enterModeCommand( editor, CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR );

            editor.addCommand( 'entermodep', enterP );
            editor.addCommand( 'entermodebr', enterBR );

            if ( editor.ui.addButton ) {
                editor.ui.addButton( 'EnterP', {
                    label: 'Enter mode P',
                    command: 'entermodep',
                    toolbar: 'paragraph,10'
                });

                editor.ui.addButton( 'EnterBR', {
                    label: 'Enter mode BR',
                    command: 'entermodebr',
                    toolbar: 'paragraph,20'
                });
            }

            editor.on( 'dataReady', function() {
                refreshButtons( editor );
            });
        }
    });

    function refreshButtons( editor ) {
        editor.getCommand( 'entermodep' ).setState(
            editor.config.enterMode == CKEDITOR.ENTER_P ? CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_ON : CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF );

        editor.getCommand( 'entermodebr' ).setState(
            editor.config.enterMode == CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR ? CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_ON : CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF );
    }

    function enterModeCommand( editor, mode ) {
        this.mode = mode;
    }

    enterModeCommand.prototype = {
        exec: function( editor ) {
            editor.config.enterMode = this.mode;
            refreshButtons( editor );
        },

        refresh: function( editor, path ) {
            refreshButtons( editor );
        }
    };
})();
```

Now add the following to `toolbar.css` in your skin file:

```
.cke_button__enterp_icon, .cke_button__enterbr_icon { display: none !important; }
.cke_button__enterp_label, .cke_button__enterbr_label { display: inline !important; }
```

...or paint some icons, if you want.

Enable the plugin when running the editor:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'id', { extraPlugins: 'entermode' } );
```

Now you can control `config.enterMode` from the toolbar.

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I'm now trying your method, but I couldn't find toolbar.css file in anywhere in my project, should I create that file in /skins/moono/ folder?

Comment: You can add it to `editor.css` since `toolbar.css` is a part of it in release versions.